# Why do I get a SQL Server error when I did not include one

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I'm currently following this tutorial for ASP.Net Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I'm having an issue: when I get to the 2nd part of the tutorial where I add a model there's a step where I enter the following commands:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Whenever I enter `Update-Database` I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)

In the tutorial it never asks you to download or connect to a SQL Server so why do I get this error?

Comment: Did you download the sample code?  Very likely it has a SQL Server connection in it.

Comment: The Prerequisites mention you need to have ASP.NET and web development workload, which would install SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB, though this is only valid if you're using VS instead of VS Code/VS for Mac

Answer (score 2):

Error is saying that you cannot connect to sql server. Unfortunately, instructions are in Part 4 in tutorial. I suggest you to follow it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I'm having a problem with this where the installation of SQL Server fails. It gives me the following error : A previous installation required a reboot... To proceed  restart your computer and then run Setup again. Of course I did try to reboot and run setup again but when I do that the error reappears and its stuck in a loop.

Comment: Uninstall if you have this or similar
Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

**You have to obviously connect to the  SQL server. if you don't this. how you expect will work `Add-Migration InitialCreate`and `Update-Database`.I assume that you did this connection. Now follow the steps below.**

**Actually, this Error basically gets when the SQL Service is stopped.**

Step 1 : Type "window" button + R ,This will open Run prompt.

Step 2: Type "services.msc" in Run prompt and hit the enter.

or go to this window you have to search the Services like this-
[image]

Step 3: Then Search for `SQLSERVER(MSSQLSERVER)` and Restart the service.if not restart then start the service.

[image]

Follow this step,hope it's resolve your issue.

Comment: Im having trouble with installing sql server and I showed the error message in a comment above.